# Filtering ng-repeat by number of days

Tags: javascript, date, angularjs, filter

So I have a simple list created with ng-repeat that contains a text filter
and a drop down menu with numbers in it that is supposed to show list elements
from that number period of time (say last 10 days):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filter.search" />
<select ng-model="filter.days">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   ...
   <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="notice in notices | filter: filter.search">
   ...
   {{notice.modified.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</li>
   ...
</li>
</ul>
```

However I am unsure just how to apply the `<select>` filter into the ng-repeat.

> Can angular do this "out of the box" or does it require a custom
>   filter and if so, any pointers on those?

Answer (score 0):

The 'filter' filter supports passing in functions as arbitrary predicates.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Specifically the expression argument has this:

function: A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of array. The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

So you could do something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="notice in notices | filter: filter.search | filter:withinDays">

$scope.withinDays = function(item) {
    // Use $scope.filter.days + notice.modified.date to do day comparison, and return true/false.
};
```